# Convert an ArrayList from file read to 2D double array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have the code bellow which reading a file to Arraylist and convert it to 2D array :

```
   public double [][] filetoArray(String fileName)
        throws IOException
    {

      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

      File aFile = new File(fileName);

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));


    String aLine = null;

    while ((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
         //result.add(aLine + ",");
         result.add(aLine);
        //aLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    String[][] data = new String[result.size()][result.size()];


   for(int i =0; i < result.size()/2; i++){
      for(int j =0; j <2; j++){
       data[i][j]= (String) result.get(j +( result.size() * i));
     }
  }
```

I have an error ( filetoarray) can not cast string to double ? i have also array out of bound exception when  just use the string type with out casting to  double?

any suggestion please

Comment: Remove "," from result

Comment: @ Vaibhav Bajaj  i remove the "," from the list ,  i still have  error ?

Comment: can you post the `stacktrace`

Comment: @novin, just so that complete data comes in "result" remove extra " aLine = reader.readLine();" from your while loop

Comment: @ Lokesh Agrawal  i comment  it

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `String` is not directly castable to `double`. What you need is `Double.valueOf(someString)` or `Double.parseDouble(someString)`.

Edit:
Looks like even if you fix this problem, you will end up with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If your list size is say 4, and at some point `i == 1` and `j == 1`, you will end up with . `1 + (4 * 1)` which is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will convert the arrayList to Double array for even number of lines in the file with data that can be parsed by class Double

```
public static double[][] filetoArray(String fileName) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    File aFile = new File(fileName);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));

    String aLine = null;

    while ((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.add(aLine);
    }
    double[][] data = new double[result.size()/ 2][2];

    int init = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size() / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(result.get(init));
            init++;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```